# Prevent iteration path to be changed

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

everyone.

Is there any way of prevent some users change the Iteration Path field? I'm using TFS 2017 on premise. I'm trying to use the rule READONLY  for certain TFS groups, but I'm getting an error that this is not supported for this field.

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No. If a work item can be edited by a user, any field is eligible to be changed.

You cannot change the behavior of the area path field, as it is a system field.